# Deshabilitar Botones dentro de un foreach

Tags: javascript, php, html

Holis espero puedas ayudarme, tengo unos botones dentro de un foreach y quisiera solucionar unas interacciones que son inesperadas.

> Quiero hacer que el boton 1 llamado editar al presionarlo deshabilite a todos los demas botones que se llamen editar y a la vez deshabiliten el toodos los botones 2 llamados cotizar.

Hasta el momento solo he logrado que deshabiliten los botones correspondientes a la misma iteracion en que estan pero no los de las siguientes iteraciones o las anteriores... espero se entienda lo que trato de hacer muchas gracias de antemano.

Primero tengo una tabla html donde muestro las consultas de una tabla de msqli, la tabla es de clientes y cada cliente tiene una `Garantia` relacionada, despues tengo un modal que se abre con el boton `VER GARANTIAS` en el que muestro todas las garantías relacionadas al cliente

***Tabla HTML***

```
<h1>Ver Clientes</h1>
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <th>Indexador</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Folio Inscripcion</th>
            <th>RUG</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        $query=mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM clientes ");
        while ($cliente=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){?>
        <tr>
               <?php  $indexador=$cliente['Id_Cliente']; ?>
            <td><?php echo $indexador; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cliente['Id_Cliente']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cliente['Nombre'].'  '.$cliente['Apellido_Paterno'].'  '.$cliente['Apellido_Materno'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cliente['Folio_Inscripcion']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cliente['RUG']; ?></td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#nueva_garantia<?php echo $cliente['Id_Cliente']; ?>" >Nueva Garantia</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#verdetalles<?php echo $cliente['Id_Cliente']; ?>" >Ver Garantias</button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#EditarCliente<?php echo $cliente['Id_Cliente']; ?>" >Editar</button>

            </td> 
        </tr>

 <!-- Modal  paara registrar garantias-->
<?php  include('../Modales/Modal_Crear_Garantia.php'); ?>

<!-- FIN!!!!! Modal  paara registrar garantias--> 

<!-- Modal  para ver detalles del cliente -->
<?php  include('../Modales/Modal_Ver_Detalles_Cliente.php'); ?>

<!-- FINN!!!!! Modal  para ver detalles del cliente -->

<!-- Modal para editar clientes -->
<?php  include('../Modales/Modal_Editar_Cliente.php'); ?>
<!-- FIN!!!!Modal para editar clientes -->
         <?php } ?> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

***Modal del boton ver detalles***

```
    <div class="modal modal-lg" tabindex="-1" id="verdetalles<?php echo $cliente['Id_Cliente']; ?>">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h3 class="text-center">Garantias de : <?php echo $cliente['Nombre'].' '.$cliente['Apellido_Paterno'].' '.$cliente['Apellido_Materno']; ?></h3>
                                <?php
                $indice=$cliente['Id_Cliente'];
                $detalles = "SELECT * FROM garantias where Id_Cliente =$indice ";
                $result = $crud->getData($detalles);
                foreach($result as $detalle){?>

 <div class="card mt-5 ml-2">
          <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-body">
               <div class="container text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                          <!-- Mostrar datos de la garantia -->
                          <form action="../Garantias/editargarantia.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control text-center " name="Id_Bien" value="<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien']; ?>">
                        <div class="col">
                              <p>Nombre:</p>    
                              <div class="mb-3">
                              <input type="Text" class="form-control text-center" name="Nombre_Del_Bien" value="<?php echo $detalle['Nombre_Del_Bien']; ?>"id="input_Nombre_Del_Bien<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien']; ?>" disabled>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="col">
                              <p>Tipo del bien:</p>
                                  
                              <div class="mb-3">
                              <input type="Text" class="form-control text-center" name="Tipo_Bien" value="<?php echo $detalle['Tipo_Bien']; ?>" id="input_Tipo_Bien<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien']; ?>"disabled>
                              </div>
                            
                          </div>
                          <div class="col">
                            <p class="text-center">Descripcion del bien:</p>
                                     
                              <div class="mb-3">
                            <input type="Text" class="form-control text-center" name="Descripcion_Bien" value="<?php echo $detalle['Descripcion_Bien']; ?>"id="input_Descripcion_Bien<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien']; ?>" disabled>
                              </div>
                              
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                            <p class="text-center">Observaciones :</p>
                                     
                              <div class="mb-3">
                            <input type="Text" class="form-control text-center" name="Observaciones" value="<?php echo $detalle['Observacion_Bien']; ?>"id="input_Observaciones<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien']; ?>" disabled>
                              </div>
                              
                            </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
                             <!-- FIN !!! Mostrar datos de la garantia -->
                             <br>
                             <!-- Botones editar -->
                              <div class="collapse" id="CollapseEdit<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien'];?>">     
                              <div class="mb-3">
                                <div class="container text-center">
                                  <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                      <button class="btn btn-btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" id="editargarantia" name="editargarantia">
                                          Guardar
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                      <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#CollapseEdit<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien'];?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" id="btnCancelarEdit" onclick="deshabilitarBntCotizar(<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien'];?>)">
                                          Cancelar
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              </div>
                              </form>
                              <!-- FIN!!! Botones editar -->
                            <br>
                            <!-- Abrir Formularios -->
                  <div class="container text-center">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>
                              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#CollapseEdit<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien'];?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" id="btneditar<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien'];?>"onclick="deshabilitarBntCotizar(<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien'];?>)">
                                Editar
                              </button>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                              <p>
                              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseCotizar<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien'];?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" id="btncotizar<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien'];?>" onclick="deshabilitarBntEdit(<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien'];?>)">
                                Cotizar
                              </button>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- FIN !!! Abrir Formularios -->
                    <!-- Formulario de Cotizar garantias -->
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseCotizar<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien'];?>">      
                      <div class="mb-3">
                        <form action="../Cotizaciones/CrearCotizacion.php" method="post">

                          <input type="hidden" class="form-control text-center " name="Id_Bien" value="<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien']; ?>" >

                          <div class="row mb-3"> 
                            <div class="col text-center">
                          <label for="Precio_LibroAzul" class="form-label text-center">Precio LibroAzul</label>
                          <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" name="Precio_LibroAzul" id="Precio_LibroAzul" placeholder="Precio_LibroAzul" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col text-center">
                          <label for="Adeudo_Vehicular"   class="form-label text-center">Adeudo Vehicular</label>
                          <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" name="Adeudo_Vehicular" id="Adeudo_Vehicular" placeholder="Adeudo_Vehicular" required>
                            </div>     
                          </div>
                          <div class="row mb-3"> 
                            <div class="col text-center">
                          <label for="Descripcion_Cotizacion" class="form-label text-center">Descripcion Cotizacion</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="Descripcion_Cotizacion" id="Descripcion_Cotizacion" placeholder="Descripcion de Cotizacion" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col text-center">
                          <label for="Observaciones_Cotizacion" class="form-label text-center">Observaciones</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="Observaciones_Cotizacion" id="Observaciones_Cotizacion" placeholder="Observaciones_Cotizacion" required>
                            </div>     
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                          <!-- Botones de Cotizar -->
                        <div class="container text-center">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                              <button class="btn btn-btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" id="cotizarargarantia" name="cotizarargarantia">Guardar</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                              <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseCotizar<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien'];?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" id="btnCancelarCotizacion" onclick="deshabilitarBntEdit(<?php echo $detalle['Id_Bien'];?>)">Cancelar</button>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
        </div>  
        </div>
        <br> 
                <?php } ?>



          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

EN este caso lo IMPORTANTE es el boton de EDITAR Y COTIZAR que estan en las cartas que muestran los detalles de las garantias.

Que hace el boton editar y cotizar EL boton editar el boton editar habilita los inputs para poder editar los campos del respectivo `ID` ademas de desplegar un boton submit que dice guardar para poder hacer un update a nivel base de datos, y un boton de cancelar que inhabilita los inputs y cierra el collapse ocultando el botón de cancelar y guardar.

Y por ultimo que es lo importante DESHABILITA con un script el boton de COTIZAR pero solo el que esta en la misma tarjeta Boton Cotizar despliega un formulario dentro de un collapse para poder cotizar esa garantia y DESHABILITA con un script el boton EDITAR pero solo el que esta en la misma tarjeta

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
    var btneditar=document.getElementById('btneditar'),
btncotizar=document.getElementById('btncotizar'),
input_Nombre_Del_Bien=document.getElementById('input_Nombre_Del_Bien'),
input_Tipo_Bien=document.getElementById('input_Tipo_Bien'),
input_Descripcion_Bien=document.getElementById('input_Descripcion_Bien'),
input_Observaciones=document.getElementById('input_Observaciones'),
contador=0;
contador2=0

function deshabilitarBntCotizar(num) {
    if (contador==0) {
        document.getElementById('btncotizar'+num).disabled=true;
        document.getElementById('input_Nombre_Del_Bien'+num).disabled=false;
        document.getElementById('input_Tipo_Bien'+num).disabled=false;
        document.getElementById('input_Descripcion_Bien'+num).disabled=false;
        document.getElementById('input_Observaciones'+num).disabled=false;
        contador=1;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('btncotizar'+num).disabled=false;
        document.getElementById('input_Nombre_Del_Bien'+num).disabled=true;
        document.getElementById('input_Tipo_Bien'+num).disabled=true;
        document.getElementById('input_Descripcion_Bien'+num).disabled=true;
        document.getElementById('input_Observaciones'+num).disabled=true;
        contador=0;
    }
    
}

function deshabilitarBntEdit(num) {
    if (contador==0) {
        document.getElementById('btneditar'+num).disabled=true;
        contador=1;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('btneditar'+num).disabled=false;
        contador=0;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

> ... quiero hacer que el boton 1 llamdo editar al presionarlo
> deshabilite a todos los demas botones que se llamen `editar` y a la
> vez deshabiliten el toodos los botones 2 llamados `cotizar`.

Esto es muy simple de hacer si asignas una clase a cada botón, en el ejemplo he añadido una clase `editar` a los botones `Editar` y una clase `cotizar` a los botones `Cotizar`.

Luego, puedes hacer dos grupos de botones, por un lado los `Editar`, para escuchar sus clicks, y por otro lado los `Editar` y `Cotizar`, para desactivarlos todos, excepto el que haya sido clickeado.

Este mismo código funcionará igual con 1 fila o con cientos o miles de filas. Y no afectará a otros botones, observa que los botones `Ver Garantias` no son afectados.

Aquí un ejemplo simplificado que puedes incorporar a tu contexto:

```js
/*
  Seleccionamos por un lado, 
  todos los botones con la clase editar
  */
var btnEditar = document.querySelectorAll('.editar');

/*
  Seleccionamos además 
  todos los botones con la clase cotizar 
  y con la clase editar
  */
var toDisable = document.querySelectorAll('button.cotizar,button.editar');

/*
  En este bloque escucharmos todos los clicks en Editar
  Y desde dentro llamamos a checkForDisable
  para que deshabilite todos los que no sean
  iguales al botón presionado
  */
btnEditar.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkForDisable(e.currentTarget);
  });
});

/*
  Esta función deshabilitará todos los botones que:
   - Tengan la clase cotizar
   - Tengan la clase editar, excepto el que ha sido presionado
   */
   
function checkForDisable(btn) {
  toDisable.forEach(function(item) {
    var isSame = item === btn;
    if (!isSame) {
      item.disabled = true;
    } else {
      item.disabled = false;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>1</td>
      <td>Nombre 1</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success cotizar" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#nueva_garantia">Cotizar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#verdetalles">Ver Garantias</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success editar" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#EditarCliente">Editar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>2</td>
      <td>Nombre 2</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success cotizar" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#nueva_garantia">Cotizar</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#verdetalles">Ver Garantias</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success editar" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#EditarCliente">Editar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>3</td>
      <td>Nombre 3</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success cotizar" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#nueva_garantia">Cotizar</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#verdetalles">Ver Garantias</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success editar" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#EditarCliente">Editar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: wow muchas gracias en verdad lo voy a probar, la verdad no se me había ocurrido además de que no se ve muy difícil implementar algo así